# How to generate a tab indented array no matter character size

Tags: java, arrays, indentation, display

I have to make a function who returns an array who'll be displayed after.
I'm trying to get it perfectly indented. This is achieved by the `String.format()`, but it really depends on content. For example, dots and spaces are displayed smaller than basic strings, so it doesn't indent my code

[image]

So how to achieve a perfect indentation, no matter character size ?

```
    public static String generateArray(String[][] myArray) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                result.append(String.format("%-20s", myArray[i][j]));
            } else {
                result.append(String.format("%-20s", (myArray[i][j] != null ? myArray[i][j] : "...")));
            }
        }
        result.append('\n');
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: If you don't know your font and the font is not `monospaced` that's impossible I'd guess?

Comment: I am using the default font of Skype (my array must be displayed in Skype), so there is any workaround if it's not a monospaced font ?

Comment: You can use a code block as mentioned in Biotox answer. Then your formatting should work as expected. I don't know of any method to align non-monospaced fonts in skype.

Answer (score 1):

Skype does have a `{code}` and `!!` that can be added to format text. Try:

`{code}My Code Here{code}`

Or:

`!! This message will be all monospace.`

Comment: Unfortunately, it does show up in skype. Tags seems to be considered as plain text